# Read lines from Socket and put each into BlockingQueue

Tags: java, sockets, blockingqueue

Can anyone provide examples in Java, or advise about implementing a class which asynchronously reads lines from a socket and puts each line into a BlockingQueue.  Assume the socket is connected, and the BlockingQueue and consumer already exists.

Edit: One more thing, it needs to have the ability to timeout after a period of inactivity, and stop immediately on command.

It's not homework, I simply have not been able to find complete examples for how to do this well, and reliably.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound like you've already done the work, to be honest. All you need to do is create a BlockingQueue and have a thread to process it which is your consumer I guess. Assuming you have a DataInputStream 'in'...

Something like this:

```
BlockingQueue<String> receivedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            receivedQueue.put(in.readUTF());
        } catch (EOFException e)
        {
            ch.getClient().disconnect();
            break;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    theQueueProcessor.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: seems simple, but what about timeout and a way to immediately stop it?

Comment: @Jack Ok so EOFException or an IO Exception will be thrown if theres a timeout or error with the connection. These will be caught and the loop is broken. run() method ends then the thread is no longer running. In my example the last thing to do in the run method before we exit is interrupt the processor thread. You can 'immediately stop' this run method by calling .interrupt on the thread running it.